# NativeScript Background Service JavaScript

Tags: android, background, nativescript

I've been trying to get Background Services working with NativeScript. I've tried to get a basic example following this tutorial.

https://ozymandiasthegreat.medium.com/android-continuous-background-services-with-nativescript-a0840fc1eceb

But to make it work with javascript. However the issues I am finding are that there are newer modules and it seems to be tricky in a JS environment.

Is there any hints to getting a basic background service just to ping a console log every second (for now, and i can then implement the geolocation part)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 11, Android began to disable the background service. "Battery saver"!

Starting from version 11+, it is forbidden to start services from the background service!

Navicescript uses api worker to implement services and background service. But this will be a service that the OS can stop to save battery.

How to bypass it?

In AndroidManifest.xml add uses-permission
SET_ALARM, SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM, REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Receiver in android 11+ Can't start the service

Comment: that's interesting, will have to look into this